# jQuery selector doesn't register the added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone please explain me why this code does what it does.

What I would like to achieve is that when the first button gets clicked javascript adds a disabled class to the second button and when the second button gets pressed with disabled class the javascript won't run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />  
<title>jQuery question</title>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
a.success { background: green }
</style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="holder">
        <a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(function(){

  $('#holder a.button:not(.disabled)').on('click', function() {

    // Toggle success class
    if($(this).hasClass('success')) {
        $(this).removeClass('success');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('success');
    }

    // Add disabled class to the not so lucky button 
    $('#holder a.button:not(.success)').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
    });

  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

Looking at the console this is not the case. Even though the second button gets the disabled class. Pressing the disabled button still runs javascript despite the :not(.disabled) selector.

It behaves as expected when I change it like this

```
$('#holder a.button').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
```

But could someone please explain why it's acting like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is not going to dynamically re-evaluate itself every time an event is fired.

The best way to solve this problem would be to use event delegation:

```
$('#holder').on('click', '.button:not(.disabled)', function() {
    // snip...
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the clarification. If anyone could suggest me some reading about the consepts of binding, dom bubbling and so forth that would truly be helpful.

Comment: Thank You for the link.
Have now had some time to work through it and gained some clear insights about how jquery/js and dom interact and come together.